Change of Variable Why Does It Have To Be Monotonic?
I understand, that for the cases where there are multiple solutions to $y = g^{-1}(x)$, then we need to account for that transformed density from the x distribution to the y distribution. That is, I understand why there might be a difference between the many-to-one and the one-to-one change of variable method.
But what I don't understand is, why the function needs to be monotone in the interval of X in the original one-to-one method, it doesn't seem like we use the monotonicity? Is there a connection between the number of solutions to $y = g^{-1}(x)$ and monotonicity? If so, I cannot find anything about it.
What I am referring to is the proof of the formula
$f_Y(y) = f_X(g^{-1}(y))|\frac{d}{dy}(g^{-1}(y))|$
For the PDF of $Y = g(x)$, where $g^{-1}$ denotes the inverse function of g. There are many variations of it, but all of them require g(x) to be monotonic in the interval of the domain of X. However, it is not stated in any of them, why this is the case.

Are you asking whether some monotonicity hypothesis of some theorem is necessary for that theorem? Assuming so, please hit the edit button and give a complete statement of the theorem, because without that statement we have no idea what you are asking. (Assuming not, things are even more confusing).

Try and apply the theorem to $g(x)=x^{2}$ and $X$ being a standard normal variate and see what you get for $Y=X^{2}$. (Spoiler: It will not be a pdf). The problem lies in the fact that $x^{2}$ is not monotonic in $(-\infty,\infty)$. However, the same formula will give you the correct pdf for $X$ being an exponential variate. (Reason: $x^{2}$ is monotonic in $(0,\infty)$)
